# A written interview question

Tags: lateral-thinking

The following exam sheets are given to each candidate interviewing with a private company:

> One guy had been working in a company for a long time and retired to move back to his home country. Before going back, he decided to go to a bar and drink beer one last time before moving back. While sitting on a table, he noticed a good-looking woman, and sent her a piece of paper saying “Do you wanna drink”, then after she received that piece of paper, she wrote something on its other side and send that paper back to him, but he tried and could not read it and showed it to his closest friend sitting next to him, his friend said “*Don't call me again!*” and left the bar. He did not understand anything and after a while he left the bar.
>
> After a day, he moved back to his home country and was still wondering what was written on this piece of paper, and asked to his father and after his father read it, he disowned his own son! He was shocked and went to his wife despairingly and showed the paper to her and she divorced him next day. He was so depressed and locked the paper into his lock. After a while, at one night some thief came and opened the lock, while stealing the money, he noticed the paper and read it, then left everything in the lock and ran away.
>
> **What is written on this paper?**

Only one candidate find the right answer and passed the exam. Can you?

Comment: You are my son?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be:

> One guy had been working in a company for a long time and retired to move back to his home country. Before going back, he decided to go to a bar and drink beer one last time before moving back. While sitting on a table, he noticed a good-looking woman, and sent her a piece of paper saying “Do you wanna drink”, then after she received that piece of paper, she wrote something on its other side and send that paper back to him, but he tried and could not read it and show it to his closest friend sitting next to him, his friend said “Don't call me again!” and left the bar. He did not understand anything and after a while left the bar.
>
>     After a day, he moved back to his home country and was still wondering what was written on this piece of paper, and asked to his father and after his father read it he disowned his own son! He was shocked and went to his wife despairingly and showed the paper to her and she divorced him next day. He was so depressed and locked the paper into his lock. After a while, at one night some thief came and opened the lock, while stealing the money, he noticed the paper and read it, then left everything in the lock and ran away.
>
>     What is written on this paper?

Explanation:

> This is what is written in the exam question.

Comment: This is the intended answer :)

Comment: @Oray oh... *facepalm* lateral thinking... ugh i'm just a little disappointed there wasn't a more clever answer.

Comment: @thecoder16 sorry for disappointment :(

Comment: @Oray funnily enough, I can find reason why this would work for the question. The girl writes it because she wants help with the exam question, the friend/father/wife are shocked he is spreading private exam information, and the thief needs to finish the exam with that answer so he quickly runs back to the testing room. Yeah, that doesn't really work :P

Comment: No offence meant, OP, but if an interviewer asked me a question like this, I'd probably think twice about joining that company.

Answer (score 7):

This is amusing but I will still give this answer:

> It was written, "Don't call me again"!

Explanation:

> He showed it to his friend. Obviously, his friend read it to him. And probably got offended.
>  Then, he showed it to his father was obviously furious at being disowned by his son.
>  When, he showed it to his wife, I guess it was the final nail in the coffin of their relationship(which was probably troubled. Otherwise, why would she divorce him on just a note?)
>  When the thief saw the note, he probably thought he was being watched. Hence, he threw everything and ran to save himself.

Comment: This (kinda) explains everything except for the thief. (Only "kinda" because it only works if the man just handed all these people the paper without any explanation, and if they jumped to conclusions and didn't ask him to explain.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, this kinda fits, although some of the explanations are a bit lame..

> "I'm seeing someone.."

This would work because

> 1. That would be a thing someone would write in response to such a question
>  2. The friend knows the guy is married, and disapproves
>  3. The father and the wife can obviously see both the sides of the paper, recognise the guy's handwriting, and realise that he's been cheating, or at least trying to.
>  4. The thief thinks he is being watched

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the correct answer (as the correct answer has already been accepted), but this, inspired by Paparazzi's comment below the question, makes more sense to me:

> "You're my brother!"

Explanation:

(I'll refer to the man with the piece of paper as A and the woman who wrote on it as B.)

Unlike what is required for some of the other answers, the man didn't just wordlessly show the various people the paper, but explained the context behind it. His friend

> thought A knew B was his sister, and was disgusted that he was so nonchalently attempting to engage in incest

His father

> knew that A would have recognised any of the other children A's father had with A's mother (as they all grew up together), and concluded that B must have been A's mother's daughter by her previous marriage who grew up with her (B's) father, meaning that (if A and B are full siblings), A's biological father must actually be A's mother's ex-husband

or

> assumed this meant B was A's half-sister (as he and his wife had no daughters), and knew that A's mother had never given birth to another child, and so concluded that B and A were related through their father

and in either case

> deduced that his wife had lied to him about A's paternity. (Harsh to disown him for this and just ignore their lifelong de facto father-son relationship, for something that isn't A's fault, but some people would act like that.)

His wife

> was simply shocked that he had hit on another woman; or they had an open relationship (which makes the most sense if he was happy telling her the story behind the piece of paper...) but, like the friend, she was shocked that he would casually attempt incest; or she was shocked by both the attempted infidelity and the attempted incest

The thief

> on seeing the piece of paper was reminded of his religious upbringing and how he had been taught that all men are brothers, and  was ashamed of himself for wanting to do something that would hurt his fellow man, and abandoned the idea. (He may also have thought the piece of paper was deliberately intended to send this message, and have concluded that the safe's owner knew he would break into it, and so felt watched, and that the attempt was too risky.)